# Parse.com orderBy from local datasore when using location

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sorting, parse-platform

I have ran into a little bit of a problem when it comes to using a query from the local datastore when it comes to the sorting objects drawn from a query that uses a `nearGeoPoint` by a key that is not the location. Here is the code for the query.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")

//I believe the problem has to do with this location whereKey
query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: geoPoint, withinMiles: mileRadius)

if isCached {
     query.fromLocalDatastore()
}
query.orderByDescending("points")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results, error) -> Void in
     //use the data
)}
```

Now, my problem is this, if the query comes from the network, there is no problem. It is sorted as I expect with the results sorted by the `points` key. However, when the query comes from the local datastore, I do not get expected behavior. The results are not sorted by `points`r. Now, I am pretty sure that the problem has to do with using `nearGeoPoint`. I believe this because when I comment out the `nearGeoPoint` line, the results are sorted by the `points` key perfectly for both the query from the local datastore and from the network.

So, my question is, if anybody who has more experience using Parse.com can shine some light on why this query is not sorting the objects like I expect. Thanks.

**Update**

I circumvented this problem by just querying by location and then sorting the results that I had received. This isn't ideal, but it works. Although, I would still like to know if anyone has anything to say about my issue.

Comment: I have the same problem can you detail more the solution

Comment: @HamzaMHIRA, I was stuck with taking out the sort descending on points and I just sorted it using swift.

Comment: Thanks for the response but where and how can you provide some code, I actually have a problem with PFQueryTableViewController